# Incorrect debugging of Win32 program on 64 bit OS

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, visual-studio-debugging

Windows 7 64 bit, Visual Studio 2010, Console C++ application, Win32 Debug configuration:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char* p = NULL;
    *p = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Start Debugging. Obviously, I get this error messsge:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x77d915de in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
```

I select Debug and see the following stack:

```
ntdll.dll!77d915de()    
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
ntdll.dll!77d915de()    
ntdll.dll!77d8014e()    
msvcr100d.dll!_heap_alloc_dbg_impl(unsigned int nSize, int nBlockUse, const char * szFileName, int nLine, int * errno_tmp)  Line 504 + 0xc bytes    C++
>ffffffff()
```

Debugger breaks on  `__finally` line in dbgheap.c. Stack is corrupted, the line `*p = 1` is missing in the stack. Output window:

```
'test.exe': Loaded 'C:\tmp\test\Debug\test.exe', Symbols loaded.
'test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
First-chance exception at 0x010f13a8 in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x77d915de in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
```

Now, if I run the same program in x64 Debug configuration, everything is OK - debugger breaks on the line `*p = 1`. How can I get correct debugging for Win32 program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debug->Exceptions->win32 Exception->c0000005 tick the box in "Thrown" column or in the "Thrown" column for entire Win32 Exceptions  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/038tzxdw(v=vs.100).aspx

```
*p = 1; 
00041375 mov eax,dword ptr [p]
00041378 mov byte ptr [eax],1
```

First-chance exception at 0x00041378 in test2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. Interesting, why it worked without this change for x64?

Comment: probably by design, Visual Studio Debugger Team must know, [Connect site for Visual Studio](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio)